# I get the opposite effect of what I want, in bash

Tags: bash

if I were to type in 7 as the first number and 4 as the multiple, i'd get 56,70,84,98, instead of 14,28,42,56

i'm trying to specify the multiples of which
number they want to print and how many of them

```bash
echo "Enter first number: " 
read num1
echo "Enter number of multiples: "
read num2

for (( num2*1; num2 <= num1; num2++ ))
do
    echo $((num1 * num2 * 2))
done
```

Comment: Why is the other output what you think should be correct?

Comment: ...that is to say, don't make us guess _why_ the output you get is "wrong" to you.

Comment: Even better, tell us _what you're trying to accomplish_, so we could tell you how to accomplish it successfully. Not what the numbers should be, but _why_ they should be that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so what I'm trying to do is specify the multiples of which 
number they want to print and how many of them

Comment: ...but... that's not what your code _does_.

Comment: Maybe you should have written something like `for (( i=0; i<num2; i++ )); do echo "$(( num1 * (i+2) ))"; done`?

Comment: But I don't know why you expect it to be `42` instead of `35` after `28`, so it's clearly not just "multiples" in the simple sense; which is to say, there's more about your question that you aren't explaining here (and are just expecting us to intuit by guesswork).

Answer (score 1):

```
bash$ num1=7
bash$ num2=4
bash$ for (( num2*1; num2 <= num1; num2++ )); do
>     echo because num1 is $num1 and num2 is $num2 and \
>         num1*num2 = $((num1*num2)) and that times 2 is $((num1 * num2 * 2))
>  done
because num1 is 7 and num2 is 4 and num1*num2 = 28 and that times 2 is 56
because num1 is 7 and num2 is 5 and num1*num2 = 35 and that times 2 is 70
because num1 is 7 and num2 is 6 and num1*num2 = 42 and that times 2 is 84
because num1 is 7 and num2 is 7 and num1*num2 = 49 and that times 2 is 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expected output, this is the script needed :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
echo "Enter first number: " 
read num1
echo "Enter number of multiples: "
read num2

for (( num=1; num <= num2; num++ ))
do
    echo $((num1 * num * 2))
done
```